# Zend_Paginator reversed order

Tags: zend-framework, zend-paginator

I have a question about the Zend_Paginator. By default pages goes like:

`<Previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... Next>`

Is this possible to have order like

`<Previous 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 ... Next>`

Comment: Extend `Zend_Paginator` class and override `_createPages` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to mess with the paginator class, you control how the pages are displayed with your [paginator control script](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.paginator.usage.html#zend.paginator.usage.rendering.example-controls).

In your control script you will find a code like:

```
<!--Number page links-->
 <td>|
      <?php foreach ($this->pagesInRange as $page):?>
            <?php if ($page != $this->current) :?>
                  <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array_merge($params, array('page' => $page)))?>">
                  <?php echo $page?></a> |
            <?php else:?>
                  <?php echo $page?> |
       <?php
             endif;
             endforeach;
       ?>
 </td>
```

This is where you can reverse the order of the pages if you choose. Just use normal PHP array functions to get the page order you desire.